# 削除を取り消す時のツールチップが「取消に投票する」

Tags: バグ, 完了

[image: 投票する]

自分で自分の投稿を削除した場合だと、取り消しは即時に反映されるので、「投票する」だと仕様に即していません。他のケースは確認していません。

修正案:

> この投稿の削除を取り消す